# Where can I place *=require rouge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rouge

I use rouge gem. When I add *=require rouge in assets/builds/application.css it works(code hightlights), but server restarted its *=require rouge deleted. I tried create application.scss and application.css in stylesheets/ but it not working(code not hightlighting). I tried add *=require rouge in stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss but not working. Where I add this code?

Comment: I resolve the problem. To application.html.erb I add <%= stylesheet_link_tag "rouge", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>, and I add to manifest.js //= link rouge.css. It works!